# Silverlight3 RTM crashing both FF and IE with error code

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

On my XP machine, I have Blend3 RTM and Silverlight3.

Since I made this update, Silverlight crash both IE and FF (error code 8013150a) as soon as the Silverlight loading animation is shown.

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Can you share any of your code or the web page address?

Comment: All Silverlight pages produce the crash...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after desinstalling and reinstalling Silverlight and the SDK everything just works fine again !